# Why should we want to quantize Gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, quantum-gravity, quantization

I understand that it will be "nice" to have a quantum description of Gravity as well, just like the other 3 forces. I would like to find out what problems arise in existing theory (not counting String Theory) that indicate that Gravity has to be quantizable?

Putting it differently - what is the motivation, apart from the appeal of elegance, for wanting to quantize Gravity?

Comment: We want to know what happened at the big bang when it was extremely young, and to do that we need a quantum version of gravity. Another motivation is Einstein's field equations suggest that the RHS which is related to the curvature should be quantised exactly like the LHS momentum-energy tensor. I have to say that there is no need to know anything, we are just looking to understand nature better. Like there's no need for you to know the answer to this question, but you still asked anyway.

Comment: And how I didn't need to answer this but I couldn't help my self because you made a childish rude asshole response so I followed suite to make you realize how it feels.m⚡️☃